# .php files are not compressing, while GZIP is set in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, compression, gzip, deflate

According to [checkgzipcompression](https://checkgzipcompression.com) all my .js and .css are correctly GZIP compressed.
Except for my php webpages:

www.website.nl/**webpages.php** seem not gzipped, resulting in a 75% increase in "wasted" data transfer. My `.htaccess` file ends with the following below. What needs to be changed here to get GZIP compression for my php webpages to work properly? (Excluding the .php files from the /includes/ folder ofcourse since those are not "transferred to the browser" and are processed internally so they need no compression). Thanks!

```
# compress speficic filetypes
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|txt|php)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages served in the browser with .php extension are considered html. PHP uses Content-Type "text/html" as default.

I would say, find out what's your web server, and then find out the correct compression method for it.

Good luck!